# Trying to get property of non-object [from the user side]

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

This is my first time use stack overflow so hope y'all can help me slove the problem (and sorry for my bad english)

my project use codeigniter 3

straight to the point
Case : When User 1 (admin) has created a form, the detail menu will appear and User 1 (admin) can see it. However, when User 2 (staff) wants to view the detail menu created by User 1 (admin), an error will occur saying "Trying to get property of non-object", both have same access but user 2 (staff) can't see detail from menu that user 1 (admin) create And vice versa.
The objects detected as non-objects are: id_barang_masuk, id_user, nama, waktu.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    
    <?php $this->load->view('layouts/_alert') ?>

    <div class="row" id="printBukti">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="card mb-3">
                <div class="card-header bg-primary text-white">
                    Detail Pemasukan Barang
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <table class="table-responsive mb-3 no-wrap">
                        <tr>
                            <td>Nomor pemasukan</td>
                            <td>:</td>
                            <td><?= $barang_masuk->id_barang_masuk ?></td> // id_barang_masuk error
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>NIP Staff</td>
                            <td>:</td>
                            <td><?= $barang_masuk->id_user ?></td> // id_user error
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Nama Staff</td>
                            <td>:</td>
                            <td><?= $barang_masuk->nama ?></td> // nama error
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Waktu</td>
                            <td>:</td>
                            <td><?= date('d/m/Y H:i:s', strtotime($barang_masuk->waktu)) ?></td> // waktu error
                        </tr>
                    </table>
```

File location: views/pages/inputs/detail.php.

And this the controller

```
class Inputs extends MY_Controller 
{
    private $id_user;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        
        $this->id_user  = $this->session->userdata('id_user');
        $is_login       = $this->session->userdata('is_login');

        if (!$is_login) {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('warning', 'Anda belum login');
            redirect(base_url('login'));
            return;
        }
    }

    public function index($page = null)
    {
        $this->session->unset_userdata('keyword');
        $this->session->unset_userdata('time');
        
        $data['title']              = 'Inventory MS - List Barang Masuk';
        $data['breadcrumb_title']   = 'List Barang Masuk';
        $data['breadcrumb_path']    = 'Barang Masuk / List Barang Masuk';
        $data['content']            = $this->inputs->select([
                'barang_masuk.id', 'user.nama', 
                'barang_masuk.waktu', 'barang_masuk.total_harga'
            ])
            ->join('user')
            ->orderBy('barang_masuk.waktu', 'DESC')
            ->paginate($page)
            ->get();
        $data['total_rows'] = $this->inputs->count();
        $data['pagination'] = $this->inputs->makePagination(base_url('inputs'), 2, $data['total_rows']);
        $data['page']       = 'pages/inputs/index';
        
        $this->view($data);
    }
```

Location File : controller/inputs.php

This process controller exists before starting access to the details menu

Other than the file in the input, there is also an output file with the same code and the same error as the input case.

I've tried using if else but it still doesn't work

```
<?php if ($barang_masuk) { ?>
    <table class="table-responsive mb-3 no-wrap">
        <tr>
            <td>Nomor pemasukan</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td><?= $barang_masuk->id_barang_masuk ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>NIP Staff</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td><?= $barang_masuk->id_user ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Nama Staff</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td><?= $barang_masuk->nama ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Waktu</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td><?= date('d/m/Y H:i:s', strtotime($barang_masuk->waktu)) ?></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<?php } else { ?>
    <p>Data pemasukan barang tidak tersedia.</p>
<?php } ?>
```

Is there anyone who can fix it?

Edit :
This is the display of the detail menu created by User 1 (admin) and viewed by the same user. However, the result will be different/error if viewed by User 2 (staff).
[Detail menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWdDO.png)

Answer (score 0):

error is probably occurring when accessing properties on $barang_masuk object.

you can check if $barang_masuk is not empty before accessing its properties.

```
<?php if (!empty($barang_masuk)): ?>
    <table class="table-responsive mb-3 no-wrap">
        <tr>
            <td>Nomor pemasukan</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td><?= $barang_masuk->id_barang_masuk ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>NIP Staff</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td><?= $barang_masuk->id_user ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Nama Staff</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td><?= $barang_masuk->nama ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Waktu</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td><?= date('d/m/Y H:i:s', strtotime($barang_masuk->waktu)) ?></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<?php else: ?>
    <p>Data pemasukan barang tidak tersedia.</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I apologize for the late response, sir. 
After I tried it from the perspective of User 2 (staff), it turns out it works the same way vice versa. However, it is not as I expected. Here, 
I want User 2 (staff) to be able to see the detail menu that has been created by User 1 (admin), not "Data pemasukan barang tidak tersedia" because User 2 (staff) should be able to see the mentioned objects. 
Is there any other way to fix it?